# SSIS - C# : script is only working if I put breakpoint (debugging mode) in it

Tags: c#, ssis, etl

my script is only working (files are being moved, no error) if I insert breakpoint on it.
this is a script to move files to another folder after ETL jobs are done.

the source files is .xls (excel file 2003) and it loops through the file and worksheet of each file.

the files are still being used somehow, after the ETL jobs are done, I still cannot move the file manually. 
I dont find any problem if I "copy" the file instead "move".

but for this task, I need to "move" the files after the ETL jobs are done.

I have tried to use "file system task" as well. it's still not working, and the error shows the files are still being used by another progress.

anyone ever has same problem ? or anyone have idea to "release" the excel file after ETL jobs are done ?

Thanks for any help

```
#region Help:  Introduction to the script task
/* The Script Task allows you to perform virtually any operation that can be accomplished in
 * a .Net application within the context of an Integration Services control flow. 
 * 
 * Expand the other regions which have "Help" prefixes for examples of specific ways to use
 * Integration Services features within this script task. */
#endregion


#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

#endregion

namespace ST_b6c4a58519344f53b083ac59c40a2b40
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        /// 


        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            //load the data from dataset


            var dsVariable = Dts.Variables["User::XlsGoodFileList"].Value;
            DataSet ds = (DataSet)dsVariable;
            DataTable statusTable = ds.Tables[0];

            //to contain the value from dataset
            string filePath = "";
            string fileStatus = "";
            List<string> fileListPath = new List<string>();
            List<string> fileName = new List<string>();

            List<string> tempSource = new List<string>();
            List<string> tempDestination = new List<string>();

            //filling the array to be used later
            foreach (DataRow row in statusTable.Rows)
            {

                filePath = row["FileName"].ToString();
                fileStatus = row["isSuccess"].ToString();

                string[] name = filePath.Split('\\');

                //filter the only correct file(s)
                if (fileStatus == "True")
                {
                    fileListPath.Add(filePath);
                    fileName.Add(name[name.Length - 1]);
                }

                //start moving the correct file(s)
                string path = @"";
                string path2 = @"";
                if (fileListPath.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fileListPath.Count; i++)
                    { 
                             path = @"";
                             path2 = @"D:\ETL TOOL\GAMC\Archive\GAMC_REPORTS\";
                            path = fileListPath[i];
                            path2 += fileName[i];
                            tempSource.Add(path);
                            tempDestination.Add(path2);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i<tempSource.Count; i++)
                    {
                        File.Move(tempSource[i], tempDestination[i]);     
                    }
                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
        }









        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: When it's "not working" what does it do? nothing or throw an error. Please never right 'working' or 'not working' because we have no idea how to troubleshoot. You could probably do all this in less code with a loop and file move task. For example this shows how to loop around an ADO dataset: https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/05/28/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-result-set-enumerator. You just need to put a file system task inside it. Script tasks in SSIS can be troublesome.

Comment: its working, the files are moved and no error, thanks for your tips, im trying it out.